# Averaging Problem from Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: measure-theory

Attached is an image which i don't quite understand:[image]

Why can he pull the value $f(x)$ inside the integral when $f$ is continuous?
Then i don't see where he uses the ball $B$ being of radius less than $\delta/2$

Comment: Just write $f(x) ={1\over m(B)}\int_B f(x)\,dy$.  Because both $x$ and $y$ are elements of the same ball of radius $r/2$, they are at most $r$ units apart, by the triangle inequality.

Comment: $f(x)={1\over m(B)}\int f(x)\, dy$ holds for any $x$, whether in $B$ or not. It is for knowing that $|x-y|<\delta$ (for $y\in B$) that we need to take $x$ to be an element of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity is not needed to pull $f(x) $ inside the integral. You need that the ball is small to employ that the difference  $f(x) - f(y)$ is small (and here you use continuity).

Comment: so is it as John suggested that because x is inside the ball, we get $f(x)=\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(x) dy$?
But then were is the $\delta/2 $ used?